# Reattaching GNU Screen session name with a common prefix

Tags: gnu-screen

I have 2 screens with session names `test1` and `test19`.

When I try to reattach to `test1` by typing

```
screen -r test1
```

Gnu Screen cannot tell the difference and pops up

```
    27082.test19  (08/10/2011 07:47:29 PM)        (Detached)
    27710.test1   (08/09/2011 12:17:47 AM)        (Detached)
```

Can I fix this without resorting to the pid number? I tried putting test1 in quotes and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in the source.

```
$>./screen -v
Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU450e8f3) 2-May-06
$>./screen -ls
There are screens on:
        6943.test19     (Detached)
        6645.test1      (Detached)
2 Sockets in /tmp/uscreens/S-foo.

$>./screen -dr test1
[detached from 6645.test1]
```

Try updating your system's package if possible. Otherwise use the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git)